# Default absolute path to grep in Linux kernel 2.6.18-128.1.10.el5

Tags: php, linux, grep, location

There was a recent change on the server I do most of my work on and all PHP exec()'s now need absolute paths. Its faster than asking IT to ask it here.

So, does anyone know where grep is by default?

Comment: The location of `grep' has nothing to do with the kernel version, by the way.

Comment: It was the only info I could get about the server OS. I figured it was better than nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be in /bin/grep

Answer (score 4):

For future use you should familiarize yourself with the ["which"](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_which.htm) command.  It will go through your default search path looking for an executable.  Normally the system paths will be included therein.  Use the -a option to find all versions of a program on your path.

So "which grep" should do the job if your path is set up correctly.

Comment: I don't have ssh access to this server.